# onSubmit not working in any browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple form.  I want to calculate the value of hidden field of form using my simple formula (divide rate from drop down by 100 and then multiply it with the estimated pay from text field.

However for some strange reason onSubmit is not working on the form. I want to calculate the above value when form is submitted but it is not being called on any browser. It is really strange problem.

Here is the code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function calc1()
{
var a= document.getElementById('inf_custom_FLRaterClassCode0').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('inf_custom_FLRaterEstimatedPayroll').value; 
document.getElementById('inf_custom_EstimatedQuote').value=parseFloat(a)/100 * parseFloat(b) ; 


}

</script>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://kg933.infusionsoft.com/app/form/process/968a6b704587136af8684f30cc8c5cf4" class="infusion-form" method="GET" onSubmit="calc1();">
    <input name="inf_form_xid" type="hidden" value="968a6b704587136af8684f30cc8c5cf4" />
    <input name="inf_form_name" type="hidden" value="Full Quote - Florida Rate" />
    <input name="infusionsoft_version" type="hidden" value="1.28.7.21" />
    <div class="infusion-field">
        <label for="inf_field_FirstName">First Name *</label>
        <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_FirstName" name="inf_field_FirstName" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="infusion-field">
        <label for="inf_field_LastName">Last Name *</label>
        <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_LastName" name="inf_field_LastName" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="infusion-field">
        <label for="inf_field_Company">Company *</label>
        <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_Company" name="inf_field_Company" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="infusion-field">
        <label for="inf_field_Email">Email *</label>
        <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_Email" name="inf_field_Email" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="infusion-field">
        <label for="inf_field_Phone1">Phone 1 *</label>
        <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_Phone1" name="inf_field_Phone1" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="infusion-field">
        <label for="inf_custom_FLRaterClassCode0">FL Rater - Class Code #2 *</label>
        <select id="inf_custom_FLRaterClassCode0" name="inf_custom_FLRaterClassCode0"><option value="">Please select one</option><option value="9519">9519</option><option value="5473">5473</option><option value="5472">5472</option><option value="9516">9516</option><option value="8393">8393</option><option value="8380">8380</option><option value="5188">5188</option></select>
    </div>
    <div class="infusion-field">
        <label for="inf_custom_FLRaterEstimatedPayroll">FL Rater - Estimated Payroll *</label>
        <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_custom_FLRaterEstimatedPayroll" name="inf_custom_FLRaterEstimatedPayroll" type="text" />
    </div>
    <input name="inf_custom_EstimatedQuote" type="hidden" value="" />
    <div class="infusion-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access an element by id but should do it by name.

Replace

```
document.getElementById('inf_custom_EstimatedQuote').value=parseFloat(a)/100 * parseFloat(b) ;
```

with

```
document.getElementsByName('inf_custom_EstimatedQuote')[0].value=parseFloat(a)/100 * parseFloat(b) ;
```

or give an id to the input you want to change before sending the form.

Comment: That works perfectly. Not sure how I missed such a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Its "onsubmit" not "onSubmit"

[event_form_onsubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp)

Comment: I think it doesn't matter when it's specified as attribute.

Comment: It doesn't matter even if you replace it with small version it is not working just checked.

Comment: Actually following code results in an alert:

<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calc1()
{
 alert('asd');
}
</script>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" class="infusion-form" method="GET" onSubmit="calc1();">
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

calc1() runs right before submitting the form. However, when you submit your form, you reload your page (to "https://kg933.infusionsoft.com/app/form/process/968a6b704587136af8684f30cc8c5cf4") and thus you never get to see the calculated results because a new webpage is opened.

Comment: But still the value that it calculates must be submitted along with the form must be there through $_POST or $_GET but value is not being changed. Also If i replace the code with alert("Hello"); it is not showing alert box meaning that function is not being called?